# .Net Api - Parent route matched for invalid nested route

Tags: c#, .net, routes, controller

I have a .Net 5 API and some nested routes as follows:

```
  [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/orders")]
  [ApiVersion("1.0")]
  [ApiController]
  public class OrdersController: ControllerBase
  {
    [HttpGet("{userId:required}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Get(string userId,
      CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
      // return the orders corresponding to the userId
    }
  }

  [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/orders/details")]
  [ApiVersion("1.0")]
  [ApiController]
  public class OrdersDetailsController: ControllerBase
  {
    [HttpGet("{orderId:required}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Get(string orderId,
      CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
      // return the order details
    }
  }
```

Below is the list of responses I get when making requests to the API:

- `GET /orders/some_dummy_user_id` returns the orders for `userId="some_dummy_user_id"`, which is OK
- `GET /orders/details/some_dummy_order_id` returns the details of `orderId="some_dummy_order_id"`, which is OK
- `GET /orders/details/` tries to return the orders corresponding to `userId="details"` which is Not OK

The question is: is it possible to make the `GET /orders/details/` request match the `OrderDetailsController` route and therefore return a 404 because of the missing `orderId` URL parameter?

Comment: The controller has a deserialization method which parses the response and create classes.  The ActionResult is the class of the parsed data.  So you have a Task<T> and the T has to be the same for both.  There is a controller at both the Client and Server.  The code you want needs to be at the Server, not the client.  The controller at the server parses the request and the controller at the client parses the response.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't. Since the `userId` parameter is a string and has no constraint. `orders/details` will be matched into `{userId:required}` route because there is no evidence to distinguish the `orders` word with `userId` string parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that unfortunately it's not possible to achieve the required scenario using only the .Net routing features. The possible solutions I see in this situation are:

1. As mentioned in [Serge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67676951/5362780), introduce a manual check and throw a 404 Exception if the `userId` matches the sub-route
2. Update the routes schema in order to prevent this scenario

As I'd like to achieve this using only the .Net routing features I've proceeded with the 2nd solution (especially as the impact on the overall routes schema wasn't major).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/orders")]
  [ApiVersion("1.0")]
  [ApiController]
  public class OrdersController: ControllerBase
  {

    [HttpGet("{userId:required}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Get(string userId,
      CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
      if(userId.ToLower=="details") throw new HttpException(404, "not found");

      // return the orders corresponding to the userId
    }

 }
```